# command inside for loop taking long time and giving timeout warning

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which runs a certain command.
Initially I simply run the command in the script and it executed successfully in about 30 sec

I wish to process the output of this script and hence I used for loop as follwos inside the same batch file:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('command') DO (
    set outputline=%%i
    do something by processing the outputline here
)
```

However, 
when i execute this "command" inside for loop, the command executes successfully but takes very long time like 2 mins instead of earlier 30 secs and also with the following in output:

```
WARNING: Name Server is shutting down due to timeout reached.
```

I do not understand the reason for this?

Comment: How much data does your *command* generate?

Comment: very less some 8-10 lines. But each of these lines is a result of something complex..its a python script. I'm running a command to run a python script with certain arguments through this batch file

Comment: You may first redirect the command output to a disk file `command > file.txt`, and then use the for loop over such a file.

Comment: thnx. I tried that but it gives a file access denied error at items , I need to add pauses in the batch script for that..which is not preffered.How do i ensure that the entire output of a 'command' in a batch file is flushed to the log file before I proceed to process this output log